# JQuery Onclick Image Show hidden table row

Tags: jquery, css

I currently have a table with 2 rows.

Row 1 has and image and row 2 is hidden.

Using JQuery I need to show this hidden row.

Here is the table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><img src="/default.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>

<tr style="display:none">
    <td><img src="/default2.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `Onlick` would be a very nice event.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("td").on("click", "img", function(){
    $("tr:hidden").show();
});
```

Who would've guessed?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, put an Id or a Class to the rows so you can refer to them.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><img src="/default.png" alt="" class="trigger"/></td>
</tr>

<tr style="display:none" id="target">
    <td><img src="/default2.png" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Then, use jQuery to add an event listener function to the event:

```
<script>
  $(".trigger").click( function(){ $("#target").show(); } );
</script>
```

As you can see, `trigger` is a class, and you tell that to jQuery using a dot: `.trigger`, while  `target` is an Id, and you must use a #:  `#target`.

You can have multiple elements with the same class, but (supposedly) only one with any given Id.

In my example you could have several images triggering the event, and one target div.

Answer (score 1):

If its always 2nd you can use:

```
$('table tr:nth-child(2)').show();
```

If you have only one and don't know the index:

```
$("tr").each(function(ele){
   $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are millions of variants :)

```
$("tr").not(':hidden').find('img').click( function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings().show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a click handler to the image that would show the hidden row.

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.hide {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('td img').click(function() {
    $('tr:hidden').show();
});
</script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Google" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide">
        <td>You clicked on the image!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```